# Getting size of users group not working in Ruby

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am gathering all of the users who have administrative privileges with `@admins = User.find_by(admin: true)`, but when I try and get the number of admins with `puts @admins.size`, I get the error `NoMethodError: undefined method 'size' for #<User:0x00000009b78988>`. I expect to get just 1. Any idea what's going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as mentioned, `find_by` will only return the first instance of record matching the given condition.

Since you want a list of all the admin, use `where`.

Also, you can turn this into a `scope` in the `User` model as follow:

```
scope :admins, -> { where(admin: true) }
```

And then call:

```
User.admins # gets a list of all the admins
User.admins.size # or User.admins.count to return the number of admins you have.
```

Comment: This is pretty slick, but how would I pluck the emails from that scope? `User.admins.email` doesn't work.

Comment: Do you want to get **one** admin? or an array of **all** the admins?

Comment: Right now, what I have above will return an array for you. To get an array of all the emails then, you can do something like: `User.admins.map(&:email)`. this will return an array of emails for all admins => `["admin@example.com", "admin2@example.com", "admin3@example.com", ...]`

Comment: I got it working like this `User.admins.each do |admin| ... end` and can grab whatever info I want from each element from your scope. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You're expecting it to return a list of all the matching `User`s, but it doesn't -- [`find_by`](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods/find_by) "finds the **first** record matching the specified conditions."

You can use `User.where(admin: true)` instead, and that should work as you intend, returning an Array of all the `User`s where `admin` is `true`.

Comment: If I change it to your suggestion, other tests break. `NoMethodError: undefined method 'email' for # User::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x000000084ed5d8>` So now for some reason, if I try and access the email field with `@admins.email`, I get this error. Any idea why?

Comment: @mjswartz Because you never said that you also wanted to get the single admin. Do you want a list of admins, which you can count, or a single admin that you can do stuff with? If you just want to count that once, keep what you have, but rename your variable and to get the count use what I posted. If you want an array, use what I posted, then iterate through or directly access the members of that array the same as you would any other.

Answer (score 1):

[`find_by`](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods/find_by) will return only the first record matching the conditions. What you want here is probably [`where`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/where)

```
@admins = User.where(admin: true)
@admins.size
```